# Show $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}S_{ij}=\sum_{i<j}S_{ij}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, summation

I am looking to prove the following
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\neq j}S_{ij}=\sum_{i<j} S_{ij},\qquad S_{ij}=S_{ji}.
$$
I am not sure how to understand why it works.  Thanks

Comment: Think about what happens if you interchange $i$ and $j$.

Comment: This expression doesn't make sense, the sums should have arguments, i.e., should be sums of *something*. Given the identity, probably you mean something like
$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \neq j} A_{ij} = \sum_{i < j} A_{ij}$ for some quantities $A_{ij}$, $1 \leq i, j \leq n$, symmetric in the sense that $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
\newcommand{\t}{\times}
\begin{array}{cccccc}
{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & {\Large\circ} & \t & \t & \t & \t \\
2 & \t & {\Large\circ} & \t & \t & \t \\
3 & \t & \t & {\Large\circ} & \t & \t \\
4 & \t & \t & \t & {\Large\circ} & \t \\
5 & \t & \t & \t & \t & {\Large\circ}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: More like a riddle than a hint.

Answer (score 3):

This is only true if the things $a_{ij}$ being summed over (missing in your question) are symmetric with respect to $i$ and $j$, which is to say $a_{ji} = a_{ij}$.

For example, if $1 \le i, j \le 3$, then $\sum_{i\ne j} a_{ij} = a_{12} + a_{13} + a_{21} + a_{23} + a_{31} + a_{32}$, 
whereas $\sum_{i < j} a_{ij} = a_{12} + a_{13} + a_{23}$ and $\sum_{i > j} a_{ij} = a_{21} + a_{31} + a_{32}$.

Now, if we have symmetry, then $a_{21} + a_{31} + a_{32} = a_{12} + a_{13} + a_{23}$. Does this look familiar?

Answer (score 3):

Since $S_{ji}=S_{ij}$, and if $i\ne j$, then either $i\lt j$ or $j\lt i$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\ne j}S_{ij}
&=\sum_{i\lt j}(S_{ij}+S_{ji})\\
&=2\sum_{i\lt j}S_{ij}
\end{align}
$$