# Double summation index notation: $\Sigma_{i<j}$ versus $\Sigma_{i\neq j}$?

Tags: summation, index-notation, summation-method

What is the difference between the summations using  $i<j$  and $i\neq j$ in the formula below:
$$\sigma^{2}(\boldsymbol{w})=\sum_{i} \tilde{w}_{i}^{2}+2 \sum_{i<j} \tilde{w}_{i} \tilde{w}_{j} \rho_{i, j}=\sum_{i} \tilde{w}_{i}^{2}+\rho(\boldsymbol{w}) \sum_{i \neq j} \tilde{w}_{i} \tilde{w}_{j}$$
[Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG0j1.png)

1. Are both summations operationally equivalent?
2. If so, why break consistency and have two competing representations?
3. Which summation is more correct, or which to use for which situations?

One of the non-best answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056976/show-frac12-sum-i-neq-js-ij-sum-ijs-ij) seem to apply, but not sure how in my case.

Comment: $\sum_{i\ne j}=2\sum_{I<j}$ here

Comment: @CalvinKhor how did you automatically convert the screenshot to maths?

Comment: they are not equivalent, one is more general than the other but if there is commutativity, you multiply by $2$. What are the variabes?

Comment: I'd say there's not enough context to be sure, but note that $i\neq j$ iff ($i<j$ OR $j<i$)

Comment: for context, I think the $\rho$s come from a symmetric correlation matrix. $\boldsymbol w$ is a vector of weights, $\sigma^2$ is variance

Comment: @develarist its not so hard to type the Mathjax of a single line, which you can learn from [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) link, but I did do it automatically with a software called `mathpix'

Comment: please make long comments answers instead

Comment: Forgive my laziness, I write comments when I do not want to provide a full and formatted answer.

Comment: it's the best answer though

Comment: Glad that my comment was helpful! Let me try to migrate my comment to an answer then :)

Comment: How is defined $\rho(\boldsymbol{w})$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{i<j}$ sums over all the possible pairs $(i,j)$ for which $i<j$ holds. Similarly, $\sum_{i\neq j}$ sums over all the possible pairs $(i,j)$ for which $i\neq j$ holds.

For example, if $i$ and $j$ can take values in $\{1,2,3\}$, then

$$\sum_{i<j}a_{i,j}=a_{1,2}+a_{1,3}+a_{2,3},$$

whereas

$$\sum_{i\neq j}a_{i,j}=a_{1,2}+a_{1,3}+a_{2,1}+a_{2,3}+a_{3,1}+a_{3,2}.$$

If the summand is symmetric, i.e., $a_{i,j}=a_{j,i}$ holds for all $i$ and $j$, these two quantities are related by

$$\sum_{i\neq j}a_{i,j}=2\sum_{i<j}a_{i,j}.$$

Comment: is it more correct to have double summation symbol, or should they be combined into one: $\sum_{i\neq j}^N w_i w_j$ or $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i\neq j}^N w_i w_j$? and are they equivalent

Comment: @develarist, Both sound equally correct to me, so it might be better to choose a more economical convention. But if you feel that the double summation notation seems ambiguous, it might be good to write $$\sum_{i,j \mathop{:} i\neq j} w_i w_j.$$ By doing so, we can clarify the summation variables.